# OpenGL GLUT Perspective

Tags: opengl, glut

I am building a scale model of buildings and landscape.  I'm using openGL and GLUT and the function gluperspective.  I know that the last two parameters of the function define the z-clipping path and can only be positive.  Well I have stuff getting rendered with a negative z value.  Well it is getting clipped which makes sense.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to stop this from clipping my things with a negative z value?  My call to the gluperspective is below.

```
gluPerspective(50.0, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, 300.0);
```

Comment: Just shift the coordinates of the vertices to make sure they are in the right range.

Comment: @stardt I thought about doing that but when I rotate it wouldn't is still rotate into the negative range since I'm rotating around the y-axis?  This is my call to the rotate function.  glRotatef(_angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: You could rotate either by transforming the points or by moving the camera. The docs for glMatrixMode() at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml may help.

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the zbuffer and the z value in 3d space. Imagine that you have a camera and are holding it up to your eye. The 1.0 is the camera's screen (i.e. the closest an object can get to you), and the 300.0 is the furthest the camera can see. These define the zbuffer's "range" (which sets up clipping).

Now what if you have an object behind you? Well then the z-VALUE (not z-buffer) is negative. How do you see it? Just turn around (effectively pointing the camera in a new direction. The z-buffer stays the same (i.e. objects closer than 1.0 or further than 300.0 are not visible), but the object that has the negative z-VALUE is not visible.

So with gluPerspective, you set up your perspective matrix (i.e. the camera's field ov view and range). Then to see objects behind you, you need to set up your view matrix (i.e. the camera's orientation).

**Edit**: So to see stuff that has a negative z-VALUE (without turning around), move your camera backwards (i.e. change your view matrix, so that it is positioned further back).

Comment: Okay I think that is exactly what I want to do.  I want to change the view matrix so that it is positioned further back.  I'm googling around trying to figure it out but how do I manually set the view matrix?  Is that done with gluperspective?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can use gluLookAt to set the view matrix. It takes the position of the camera (your eye position), the look at position ( the point you are staring at with the camera, and an up vector (the direction of the sky, which is usually (0, 1, 0)).

Comment: "Well then the z-VALUE (not z-buffer) is negative." This is incorrect. Eye space (as defined by the perspective matrix as generated by `gluPerspective` or `glFrustum`) has +Z going _behind_ the viewer. -Z is forward. That is, in _eye space_, objects that are farther away have a larger negative Z than those closer. The reason these functions take positive Z values is because it makes them a bit easier to use.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are correct in terms of eye space. However, based on the description given by user1024157, I assumed that their view was set up such that positive z values in World space were in front of the camera. Hence, I was giving my explanation in World space.

Comment: @user1024157 Setting the view matrix is not only not done with `gluPerspective` (but  e.g. with `gluLookAt` or some of the *glTransform* functions), but even more important it is not done on the projection matrix stack, but the modelview matrix stack. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, get a good OpenGL or general computer graphics learning resource.

Comment: Okay a huge thank you to all of you!  I've got it fixed and you all helped me understand it better.  Wish I could give all of you points for your help but anyway.  Thanks again!